# The Power of Compounding

Tags: algorithm, formula

Suppose a Person deposits a Corpus to the bank **monthly**. The Bank pays him interest every month.
Now for given **Investment Corpus P**, **Rate of Interest R** and, **Tenure T**,
I want to calculate the **Total Amount** after the end of the tenure.

If you [google](https://www.google.com) the term **Power of Compounding** you can find thousands of online calculator for this problem.

Let’s take an example (*Note:* It’s different from the simple problem of Compound Interest):

```
If P is 52.5, R is 3.6% Anually, T is 5 Months, Suppose Total Amount is A
Now, R will be 0.3% monthly (since bank pays him every month)

After First Month:  A = 52.5*(1 + 0.003) = 52.6575 [His Corpus with added Interest]

                      **Then he Deposit Corpus again**

After Second Month: A = (52.5 + 52.6575)*(1 + 0.003) = 105.4729725

After Third Month:  A = (52.5 + 105.4729725)*(1 + 0.003) = 158.4468914

After Forth Month:  A = (52.5 + 158.4468914)*(1 + 0.003) = 211.5797321

After Fifth Month:  A = (52.5 + 211.5797321)*(1 + 0.003) = 264.8719713 ~ 265
```

So, The Answer will be 265.

An Implimentation to the problem may be like this: (Python 2)

```
p=float(raw_input('Enter the Corpus: '))
r=(1+float(raw_input('Enter the Annual Rate: '))/1200)
t=input('Enter the Tenure: ')

a=p+0
m=1
while m<t:
    a=(a+p)*r
    m+=1

print 'Total Amount',int(round(a))
```

I know this is not the best way. I tried hours to derrive the general formula for this problem, but failed. So, I wan't to know if there exists any **Formula** for this problem or any better **Algorithm**.

Comment: What's wrong with this way?  This algorithm looks pretty simple.  Are you looking for a closed-form solution for analytical purposes?

Comment: Truily speaking I am looking for any formula which will make the complexity of my algorithm in order of O(1).

Comment: What's `n`?  I don't see it in your problem statement above.

Comment: I am sorry, I mean linear complexity in terms of time. No matter what the input will be, the result will take almost the same time to calculate. In other words, the output time will not depend on the input directely.

Comment: Google 'compound interest formula' to find many pages explaining this for both continuous and periodic compounding. There are closed form solutions that run in O(1).

Comment: @DaveGalvin I just tried and none of the sites explained how to factor monthly payments into a closed-form solution.

Comment: @GuyGreer: It's called "Rentenrechnung" in German, but I have no idea what the correct financial mumbojumbo majically term in the English money world is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

let say the function `A(t)` is the Total amount after maturity period of `t` months, `P` is the corpus, `r` is `(Monthly Rate of Interest + 1)` or `r=R+1`.

Now,

```
A(1)= P*r

A(2)= (A(1) + P)*r
    = (P*r  + P)*r
    = P*r^2 + P*r

A(3)= (A(2) + P)*r
    = (P*r^2 + P*r)*r
    = P*r^3 + P*r^2 + P*r

A(t)= P*r^t + P*r^(t-1) + ... + P*r^3 + P*r^2 + P*r
    = (P*r) * [P*r^(t-1) + P*r^(t-2) + ... + P*r^2 + P*r + 1]
    = (P*r) * (r^(t-1)-1) / (r - 1)                   [Formula of sum in G.P.]
    = (P*r) * (r^(t-1)-1) / R                         [Since r = R + 1]

Or, only in terms of P, R, t:
A(t) = P*(1 + R) * ((1 + R)^(t-1)-1) / R
```

That's the simple **Geometric Progression** when we consider `r=R+1`.

Now, take example given,
`P=52.5` `R=0.003` `t=5`

```
r = 1 + R = 1.003
A = A(5) = (52.5 * 1.003) * (1.003^5 - 1) / 0.003 = 264.87197128801836 ~ 265
```

Thank You [GuyGreer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1277769/guygreer) for your **precious time and effort**. I got the idea to consider `r=R+1` from your answer only which solvs the problem, Otherwise I have spent hour to break it into simple equation.

Answer (score 2):

We can find a closed-form solution to the following problem (very slightly different from what you stated, but the solution will work either way):

```
  a(n+1) = a(n) * r + p
  a(0) = A

  a(1) = A*r + p

  a(2) = a(1)*r + p
  a(2) = (A*r + p)*r + p
  a(2) = A*r^2 + p*r + p

  a(3) = a(2)*r + p
  a(3) = (A*r^2 + p*r + p)*r + p
  a(3) = A*r^3 + p*r^2 + p*r + p
  ...
```

[image]

This sum is a geometric series, which you can find out, by googling a bit, simplifies to:

[image]

This can be solved in O(1) using an O(1) `pow` function to compute the powers.

Comment: Also, you might want to use http://www.zahlen-kern.de/editor/equations/a40a.png and http://www.zahlen-kern.de/editor/equations/a40g.png (and add the Python code for completeness?)

Comment: @Zeta Well, you convinced me.  Also bookmarking that site for future reference.

Comment: @GuyGreer I appreciate your affort, but look at the question again, My problem doesn't fit to the function a(n).

Comment: @AbhishekKashyap I fail to see what the problem is, what am I missing from your question that makes this incompatible?

Comment: @GuyGreer a(2)=(a(1)+p) * r instead of a(1)*r + p in my problem.

Comment: Oh I got the Solution!

Comment: @GuyGreer Thank you. by considering r=1+R the problem becomes the simple G.P. I got the idea of takinf r=1+R from your answer, otherwise I couldn't have solved the problem. Thanks again.